# Does energy of electric field depend on charge put in it?

Tags: electric-fields, coulombs-law

My friend told me that energy of electric field depends on charge put in it. Here is his proof:

Consider we have 2 charges like the picture and charge 1 is stand still.[image]

Since the system "electric field 1 and charge 2" is isolated (because they don't interact with electric field 2 and charge 1), we have

$ΔE_1 +  ΔE_2 = 0$

(with $E_1$ and $E_2$ are energy of electric field 1 and charge 2)

But,

$ΔE_2 =  ΔK = kq_1q_2(\frac{1}{r_1} - \frac{1}{r_2})$

(= work done by electrostatic force) is

$ΔE_1 = kq_1q_2(\frac{1}{r_2}- \frac{1}{r_1})$

This show that $E_1 = \frac{kq_1q_2}{r}$ (with $r$ is the distance from 1 to 2)

So, energy of electric field 1 depends on $q_2$ that put in it, i.e. depends on charge put in it?

Comment: No work against an electric field is required to move a charge in a space which is devoid of an electric field. So two charges are the minimum where such work is required. Now, I think you're confused about the symmetry of the situation: once you put a second charge there, and hence define its electric potential energy, because of the symmetry of the potential arising between the charges $E = \frac{kq_1q_2}{r}$ you may well exchange $q_1$ and $q_2$ and get the same result. In other words, bringing the other charge into this field would require exactly the same amount of energy.

Answer (score 0):

*(with E1 and E2 are energy of electric field 1 and charge 2)*

There is no $E_1$ or $E_2$ which to me implies you can pick out the contribution to the electric potential energy made by each of the charges.

Sure you can think of each charge producing an electric field and then adding the two fields as vectors to find the resultant field but $kq_1q_2/r$ is the electric potential energy of the **system** of two charges $q_1$ and $q_2$ with separation $r$.
That is why it does not matter how the final state of two charges $q_1$ and $q_2$ with separation $r$ is reached.
You could start with charge $1$ and move charge $2$, then move charge $1$ and then move charge $2$, etc until they have a separation $r$ but whichever way you do it the electric potential energy of the system of two charges at a separation $r$ will always be the same.